# How to reduce the Pod dependencies of Firebase Analytics?

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

All I really need is the Firebase analytics dashboard (I don't really need the Google Analytics integration) plus the crashlytics.

When I add these two Pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
```

I get so many others installed as well:

```
Installing Firebase (6.27.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (6.6.1)
Installing FirebaseCore (6.8.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.4.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (4.2.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (1.4.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (6.2.1)
Installing GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (3.2.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities 6.6.0
```

The size is 2.1 MB larger than installing my app including Microsoft App Center. That's massive.

I don't need all the extra features that Firebase is offering, neither auth, nor push or any form of distribution.  All I care is the analytics dashboard and crashlytics reports.

Is there a way to fine tune this? I really need to decrease the size of my app, but I don't want to lose out on firebase analytics capabilities.

Comment: It looks like it's just adding common libraries shared between many Firebase products.  I doubt that removing any one of them would be healthy.

Comment: Google is very inconsiderate about binary size. They are throwing in the kitchen sink with it.

Comment: If you have feedback about the SDKs, I suggest filing that with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support